# making functions in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I`m making some functions with Jquery.
but I got problem.

```
function fader(elm,delaytime) {
    elm.each(function(index){
        $(this).css('visibility','visible').delay(delaytime*index);
        $(this).fadeIn(1500);
    });
}
fader($('.subImgs').children(),200);
```

It was good, and I wanted more.

```
$.fn.fader2 = function(elm,delaytime) {
    elm.each(function(index){
        $(this).css('visibility','visible').delay(delaytime*index);
        $(this).fadeIn(1500);
    });
}

$('.subImgs').children().fader2(200);
```

It doesn't work. I know something was different but I couldn't find it.
anyone can help me?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring to learn the basics of jQuery plugin development. Your code does not work because `elm` has the value `200`. It does not refer to the selected elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also try:

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.myFader) {
        $.extend({
            myFader: function(elm, delaytime) {
                return elm.each(function(index){
                    $(this).css('visibility','visible').delay(delaytime*index).fadeIn(1500);
                });
            }
        });
        $.fn.extend({
            myFader: function(delaytime) {
                return $.myFader($(this), delaytime);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This should allow both

```
$.myFader($('.subImgs').children(),200);
```

and

```
$('.subImgs').children().myFader(200);
```

Comment: I didn't know such this method is. Thank you very much.

Comment: No prob, that is some insight on how to begin a jquery plugin, for more, check out there [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: You don't necessarily need `.extend()`. In fact, `.extend()` is slower that just saying `$.fn.method = function() {}`.

Also, `$.fn.myFader` doesn't need `$(this)`; it only needs `this`, because `this` refers to the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

Your function should probably read:

```
$.fn.fader2 = function(delaytime) {
    return this.each(function(index){
        $(this).css('visibility','visible').delay(delaytime*index).fadeIn(1500);
    });
}
```

Working fiddle (slighty different code for better visibility): http://jsfiddle.net/2HMWF/

See the link from the comment above for great information on that topic: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Thanks for your help. short and perfect!
and thanks for your comment. The doc really helps me.